# How do I assign a domain name to a Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have completed a set of functions and am in progress to develop the UI using html templates (see below)

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

I believe that I am supposed to deploy as a web app to make it accessible online to all users. However, how do I assign a web domain name to the web app I've deployed?

Comment: I can't say for sure whether or not Google Apps servers are configured properly for this, but the general-case scenario is to set an A or AAAA (for IPv6) record in your domain manager associating a domain or subdomain with the IP of the server hosting your web app.

Comment: cant access google servers..

Comment: You shouldn't have to. Simply launching your application should either give you an IP address, or a URL you can `nslookup` the IP address of.

Comment: When you deploy your appscript as a web app, you will get a link with '/exec' in the end. You can share that link with people so that they can use your web app. To keep track of their access, you will get options when you  click **deploy as web app** from the menu. Alternatively, you can assign your script to google site and then share that site with the users. Hope you know what I'm talking about.

Comment: I have "Forwarded" a subdomain and configured it to forward with masking.  I can even pass arguments as long as I add some garbage text before the ?  in the url.  What I have yet to work out though is getting the app to display responsive pages.  It works with the raw URL and resizes on my phone, but not the forwarded version.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this!

The crucial step is adding the .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL) enum to your HtmlServe like so:

```
return HtmlService
     .createTemplateFromFile('login')
     .evaluate()
     .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
```

Then you can simply take your Apps Script URL and embed it on any webpage you like. It even supports SSL if you have that enabled on your server.

```
<iframe src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/exec"></iframe>
```

> Source:
>   https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/x-frame-options-mode

Comment: Its correct. Inclusive, if you use a subdomain linked to google site, it function.
I have an embeded script on a google site.
Example: sites.google.com/midomain.com/misite ---> misubdomain.midomain.com
Thanks for you comment... it function for me.